# Open source cache for Servlet

Tags: java, caching, servlets, memcached, guice

I need cache for my web application, it stores some small/medium size objects to cache and possibly some max 1-2mb files to cache. What open source solution would be good for this usage? Cache should be easy as Google App Engine cache (example. cache.put("key", "value"); cache.get("key");). I use Google Guice and Servlet, nothing else (so I don't need any Spring etc. recommendations) and I'm using Jetty to run my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use:

- [Memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html)
- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/googleappengine)

As you can see above, both support GAE well.

Comment: He's comparing what he wants to App Engine; he isn't running _on_ App Engine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ehcache:  http://ehcache.org

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan):

- It's primary API extends java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.
- Support for GAE is planned.
- Infinispan is developed in Java SE 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider

http://commons.apache.org/jcs/

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own cache using the Singleton Pattern and have the cache be a map. A good example of this is the service locator pattern that can cache things like data sources.